# how to print on lldb an assembly global string variable

Tags: assembly, lldb

I'm playing around with Assembly and I'm trying to print dst and src define like this:

```
.section __DATA,__data
  src:
        .string "hey Hello"
  dst:
        .space 20
```

p src outputs in HEX, but what I really want is printing the ASCII chars for a proper debugging:

```
(lldb) p src
(void *) $3 = 0x4141414141414141
```

Comment: @NateEldredge actually I get `error: failed to read memory from 0x4141414141414141`

Comment: 0x41... is neither the value nor the address.  (e.g. ASCII `H` is 0x48).  Is there maybe another symbol of the same name defined somewhere, maybe another non-global label like this one in libc?  (And BTW, if you want to reply to Nate, comment under his answer.)

Comment: I've recompiled it and actually I get `(lldb) x/s src
0x6c6c654820796568: ""`

Comment: That looks plausible for a qword, since x86-64 is little-endian; it at least includes 0x48 in there somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `x/s &src`.

```
(lldb) x/s &src
0x00004010: "Hello"
```